# Second answer is not showing in memory

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I started learning assembly for college and I have a project to present. It doesn't have to be so complicated, and decided to have the program that solves (a+b-c)!. The program doesn't show that is any error and it is calculating rez at 1st and puts it in the memory, and after, it solves the fact and when the 'MOV CX, AX / MOV fact, CX' intstructions need to be run, the fact var is not put in the memory. Like, it still shows 00 00 instead of 18.

This is the code:

```
; (a+b-c)!; la nivel de W, zona de mem distincte
segm_stiva        SEGMENT

            stiva     DB 128 DUP (?)

segm_stiva       ENDS

 

segm_date        SEGMENT

                        a DW        23  
            b DW         1
            c DW        20
            fact DW          ?
            rez DW       ?
            msg      DB  "p- Tarcuta Vasile!",'$'

segm_date        ENDS

 

segm_cod         SEGMENT

            ASSUME CS:segm_cod, DS:segm_date, SS:segm_stiva

                               et:        MOV AX, segm_date

                                          MOV DS, AX

 
                                          MOV    AX, a      
                                          ADD    AX, b
                                          SUB    AX, c      
                                          MOV   rez, AX     
                        
                        MOV AX, rez
                        MOV DS, AX
                    
                    start:      MOV CX, DS
                        MOV AX,1
                    iar:  
                        MUL CX
                        LOOP iar
                        
                        MOV CX, AX
                        MOV fact, CX
                        
                         
                        
                        MOV AX,4C00H
                        INT 21H
        
segm_cod  ENDS  
END et  
END start
```

Comment: What's the register value at that point, is it non-zero?  If it is zero, of course the memory will be zero after the store.  Your loop correctly avoids multiplying by `0`, but if the input to your factorial loop was large, too many even numbers mean too many powers factors of 2; for example 19! is a multiple of 2^16, so all 16 bits of AX would be zero.

Comment: The other likely problem is that you change the segment register DS before the loop for no apparent reason, setting it to a value from the input data, not a segment address calculation!!  So yeah, `mov fact, cx` is very likely not going to write the static storage you reserved in `segm_date SEGMENT`.  Don't do that, set up segment registers once at the start of the program and then don't mess them up.  Just `mov cx, ax` without touching DS.

Comment: @PeterCordes I deleted the DS line before the loop and ran the program, but now the loop doesn't stop

Comment: There are 2 lines involving DS before the loop.  Remove them both, and set CX directly from AX, like I said in the last sentence of my last comment.